# Most important items from a feed to save in a DB

Tags: php, feed, simplepie

I'm building a feed aggregator. I have a lot of blog addresses and I want to save all the posts in a database. I'm using Simplepie to get feeds  and then with php I'm inserting them into a database. Simplepie's API is very large, and I don't know which parts of the post I should save. So far I'm saving:

- ID
- Title
- Date
- Permalink
- Author
- Description
- Content

I want to know what other things I should save in the database. I don't know the whole API and it's pretty long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just take a reverse engineer approach.

Pick a handful of feeds that you already have and view the url source to see what tags are in the feed. After checking a few you should be able to determine what most feeds contain and decide how to setup your db.

For example this is a feed url:

feeds.feedburner.com/webresourcesdepot?format=xml

You can put that in your browser, view source, and then find a section with feed content and determine what tags they have.

You could also go through the RSS specs and take a look at all the valid options for a valid RSS feed.

http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html

Comment: That's what I did, but there are so many options and I don't want to miss anything

Comment: You could make a table with all the RSS specs or just take a look at what most sites use. Maybe take a look at ten feeds and make sure the list you have covers everything. The list you have looks like what most feeds will have. The only other thing you might want is the image of the feed.